# updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) stuck in an infinite loop on certain devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spannable

I am using an alpha interpolation on a custom `CharacterStyle` by setting an alpha value `mAlpha` and then updating the color in `updateDrawState(TextPaint tp)`.

I'm running into an issue on newer Android devices, specifically devices running API 23 don't seem to render the `Spans` at all. On older devices the updates work properly.

Has anyone dealt with this issue?

Here is the code for the alpha being set inside `onDraw` in a custom `EditText` for some weird reason the characters sometimes do not show up on certain devices on other devices the animation works perfectly:

```
// If the view is animating (meaning we set the text) go ahead and draw the animations
    if (mIsAnimating) {

        long delta = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() - mStart;

        // Initialize our word span
        FadeWordSpan[] words = mFadeText.getSpans(0, mFadeText.length(), FadeWordSpan.class);

        // Get our length
        final int length = words.length;

        // For each letter animate in the word
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            // Get our word
            FadeWordSpan word = words[i];

            long value = (delta - (i * mDurationPerWord));

            // Calculate our delta
            float dx = (float) Math.max(Math.min(value, mDurationPerWord), 0);

            // Calculate the alpha based on the delta dx value
            float alpha = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(dx / (float) mDurationPerWord);

            // Set our interpolation alpha
            word.setAlpha(alpha);

        }

        boolean keepRedrawing = delta < mDurationPerWord * length;

        // If our delta is less than the duration per word times the length then we need to keep re-drawing
        if (keepRedrawing) {

            // Call redraw on animation change
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                postInvalidateOnAnimation();
            } else
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);

        // Else let our listener know we are done animating
        } else {

            // Go ahead and set our characters styles
            FadeWordSpan[] letters = mFadeText.getSpans(0, mFadeText.length(), FadeWordSpan.class);

            for (FadeWordSpan word : letters) {
                mFadeText.removeSpan(word);
            }

            // Some animating
            mIsAnimating = false;

            // If our listener is not null go ahead and let the delegate know we have finished
            // animating in the text
            if (mAnimatingTextFinished != null) {
                mAnimatingTextFinished.onFinished();
                mAnimatingTextFinished = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

## UPDATE:

#### Devices that work are:

- Samsung S6
- HTC Devices
- Nexus 4

#### Devices that don't work are:

- Samsung S3
- Motorola Nexus 6
- Nexus 5

## Update 2:

After debugging, it seems to be that `updateDrawState(TextPaint tp)` never stops on the devices that don't work. Maybe it's blocking the part of the app that needs to render the text in.

## Update 3:

StackTrace:

[image]

## Update 4: Word Span Class

```
public class FadeWordSpan extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {

    private float mAlpha = 0.0f;

    public FadeWordSpan() {
    }

    public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
        this.mAlpha = Math.max(Math.min(alpha, 1.0f), 0.0f);
    }

    public float getAlpha() {
        return mAlpha;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {

        // This constantly gets called on certain devices
        Log.i(TAG, "updateDrawState: ");

        int red = Color.red(Color.WHITE);
        int green = Color.green(Color.WHITE);
        int blue = Color.blue(Color.WHITE);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(Color.WHITE);

        int color = Color.argb((int) (alpha * mAlpha), red, green, blue);

        tp.setColor(color);
    }

}
```

## Update 5:

Stack Dump (same as above, gets called infinitely):

```
W: java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
W:     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:490)
W:     at com.customapp.utils.views.text.FadeWordSpan.updateDrawState(FadeWordSpan.java:43)
W:     at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:953)
W:     at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:417)
W:     at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:296)
W:     at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:270)
W:     at android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:311)
W:     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6875)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
W:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
W:     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
W:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
W:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
W:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
W:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
W:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
W:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
W:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
W:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
W:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
W:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
W:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
W:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
W:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
W:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your `FadeWordSpan` span class

Comment: Done it's posted up.

Comment: Here's a link to a fuller set of code, I posted parts of it in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953863/how-to-alpha-translate-animate-each-word-in-a-textview-instead-of-each-charact

Comment: I've seen that blog before, I don't think it does anything since `updateDrawState(TextPaint tp)` will still get called. When a span is set and the view is invalidated it gets called infinitely on certain devices.

Comment: Did all that before, onDraw stops getting called after the timer runs out but updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) keeps getting called infinitely from that stacktrace I posted above

Comment: Might be a good idea? But running the debugger like above shows the trace as well, can try that now.

Comment: Posted Stack dump above, it's the same as the debugger

Comment: I get the same thing, when I extend `ForegroundColorSpan` and add a `super(color)` for the constructor.

Comment: The logcat dump was the same stack trace!

Comment: Ahhh I see the hyperlink now, didn't catch that before will test it!